Mongoose search by nested model object
I have some kind of product filtering logic.
In the Products model, I search for certain products by query parameters, which are pushed into an array of settings (queryConditions), if such filtering exists
This is one of the objects that exists in the Products model
{
    "products": [
        {
            "_id": "6612fee192f83be6c8f1f14a",
            "name": "Iphone 15",
            "__t": "Phones",
            "price": "105990",
            "color": "Белый",
            "memory": "128",
            "screen": "2480 x 1080",
            "fps": "240",
            "sim": "eSim",
            "preview": "3e26f117-e925-4303-adb5-930874e7ea21.png",
            "images": [
                "3db588ef-63f6-4596-8284-f02f4e465765.png",
                "e9437348-eb56-4537-8c13-cbbb697bcc41.png"
            ],
            "category": {
                "_id": "6612b3c9a56d07ad6a21e332",
                "name": "Телефоны",
                "preview": "phones.png"
            },
            "type": "6612b4a9a56d07ad6a21e384",
            "count": 1,
            "createdAt": "2024-04-07T20:15:29.009Z",
            "updatedAt": "2024-04-07T20:15:29.009Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ],
    "count": 1
}

Filtering logic
import { mongoose } from 'mongoose'
import ProductsModel from '../models/ProductsModel.js'

class ProductsController {
    async getAll(req, res) {
        // Filters
        const { search, color, date, category, price } = req.query
        const limit = 10
        const page = Number(req.query.page) || 1
        const skip = (page - 1) * limit

        const queryConditions = []
        const sortConditions = []

        if (search) {
            queryConditions.push({ name: new RegExp(search, 'i') })
        }

        if (color) {
            queryConditions.push({ color: color })
        }

        if (category) {
            // queryConditions.push({ type: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(category) })
            queryConditions.push({ 'category._id': new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(category) })
        }

        console.log(category)

        if (price === 'up') {
            sortConditions.push(['price', 1])
        }

        if (price === 'down') {
            sortConditions.push(['price', -1])
        }

        if (date === 'old') {
            sortConditions.push(['createdAt', 1])
        }

        if (date === 'new') {
            sortConditions.push(['createdAt', -1])
        }

        const products = await ProductsModel.find()
            .populate({ path: 'category', select: ['name', 'preview'] })
            .and(queryConditions.length > 0 ? queryConditions : [{}])
            .sort(sortConditions)
        // .skip(skip)
        // .limit(limit)

        const count = await ProductsModel.find()
            .and(queryConditions.length > 0 ? queryConditions : [{}])
            .countDocuments()

        return res.json({ products, count })
    }

export default new ProductsController()


Products Schema
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose'

export const productsDiscriminatorKey = 'productKind'

const ProductsSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: { type: String },
    },
    { productsDiscriminatorKey, timestamps: true }
)

export default model('Products', ProductsSchema)


Category Schema
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose'

const CategoryModel = new Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true,
        },
        preview: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        types: [{ type: Object }],
    },
    { timestamps: true }
)

export default new model('Category', CategoryModel)


Phone Schema
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose'

import ProductsModel, { productsDiscriminatorKey } from './ProductsModel.js'

const PhoneSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        price: { type: String, required: true },
        color: { type: String, required: true },
        memory: { type: String, required: true },
        screen: { type: String, required: true },
        fps: { type: String, required: true },
        sim: { type: String, required: true },
        preview: { type: String, required: true },
        images: [{ type: String, required: true }],
        category: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Category',
        },
        type: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Type',
        },
        count: { type: Number },
    },
    { productsDiscriminatorKey }
)

const PhoneModel = ProductsModel.discriminator('Phones', PhoneSchema)
export default PhoneModel


Filtering by search name and color works correctly, but when I try to get an object whose category is equal to the category that I pass through query, I get an empty array.
Actually, the question is how to properly implement a search for a nested category object and get an object whose category id corresponds to the id that I pass through query

What is category in the req.query? Is it an ObjectId for example '660c892cb65f2f1f584144ca' in your document?

Yes, but I tried to find both by name and by ObjectId, the result is the same

Can you post your Product schema because your query looks fine. It may be your skip that is the issue.

Added a schema. Products is just a container for all products

If your query finds 1 doc but your skip is 2 then you will get an empty array. Comment out the skip to make sure your query finds what you expect.

It still returns an empty array :(

How are you implementing the category field? Is it a subdocument of an inherited schema? Post the schema for that one as it looks like ProductsSchema is the base schema.

You posted the Category Schema but it's the PhoneSchema I need to see. The one that defines what category is. I assume PhoneSchema inherits from ProductsSchema.

It's likely that there is no Query Casting for your category._id query parameter. You can overcome this by creating a new instance of mongoose.Types.ObjectId like so:
if(category){
   queryConditions.push({ 'category': new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(category) })
}


But doesn't mongoose automatically add the id field in its schemas?

Yes, mongoose does but your are querying here so that's a separate topic. Your category will be passed as a string in req.qery but if it's an ObjectId mongoose will normally cast it to an ObjectId for you during the query. Since you are using inheritance it's probably not being cast to an ObjectId so by doing  new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(category) you are converting the query from a string to an ObjectId. Alternatively you can just use the PhoneModel instead of the ProductModel if you know you will be querying on  category.

Yeah, I got the logic. But unfortunately, I still get an empty array. Added Phone Schema to the question

Did you do new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(category) and remove the skip() to see if you find at least 1 document?

I just read your PhoneSchema. Your query should be { 'category': new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(category) }. I will update the answer. category will be what is stored in the database, not category._id. There is no _id until the populate executes.

Yes, I did everything as you advised. By the way, I tested something. In this array of Products, I have now added a new type field to the objects. Now, when I try to find a certain object by type, passing the ObjectId of this type accordingly (I passed it to the category query), then everything works fine and the object is located. But as soon as I try to find a category (of course, I change the ObjectId to the corresponding category id), an empty array is returned to me again. I think the problem is, it's like it can't reach the nested _id field in category. Updated the code in quest.

Oh yes, it works. Once again, thank you VERY much
